# Run a pre-commit hook if the file is modified under a specific directory

Tags: git, github, githooks, pre-commit-hook

My project has client code and server code in one project

I want to run the test code through the pre-commit hook only when the client code has been modified.

Is there a way to run a pre-commit hook only when a file is modified under a specific folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hook cannot be prevented from executing, but you can prevent the bulk of the script from running using a conditional.

`git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=ACM src/` will return the list of files added, copied or modified in the `src/` folder.

In your hook script, check the number of lines that are output from the `git diff` command using `wc -l`, and exit the hook early if the output is "0".

Comment: Can you please provide a gist illustrating this ?